# Параллельная загрузка файлов в python/bash

Tags: python, многопоточность, bash, multiprocessing, wget

Как лучше организовать параллельную загрузку очень больших файлов (50-1000гб) файлов из разных источников в python3 и стоит ли делать так вообще?
Изначально предполагалось использовать wget (с опцией -с) через python subprocess, но скорость загрузки файлов очень разная, есть которые загружаются быстро, с ними все ок, а есть те которые загружаются крайне медленно, что по видимому не связано со скоростью моего интернета, а связано со скоростью раздачи. Очень не хочется ждать пока все эти медленно загружаемые файлы будут скачиваться последовательно, поэтому хорошо бы организовать это параллель. Но боюсь наткнуться на подводные камни, так как не очень понимаю в многопоточности и многоядерности. С одной стороны можно использовать multithreading, но даст ли это прирост скорости загрузки разных файлов? Не упрусь ли я в ограничение на скорость записи файлов в своей системе? Или может лучше multiprocessing? Тут вообще не знаю чего ожидать можно, может лучше будет, а может и нет... В общем как это лучше организовать?

Comment: Все эти вопросы в общем-то не имеют отношения к питону. Проверяйте скорость вашего диска, проверяйте скорость вашего интернета, проверяйте скорость отдающих файлы серверов

Comment: Пишите тест. Это просто. Измеряйте параметры. Будут конкретные вопросы - спрашивайте.

Comment: Ты расскажи нафига тебе это на самом деле. Чё за файлы, откуда качаешь, куда кладёшь и как потом используешь. Я уже набросал у себя в голову примерно 3 сценария. И у каждого из них - разные пути решения, но каждый из них - подходит под твоё описание задачи.

Comment: @don Rumata
Файлы это базы данных как правило в форматах tsv, txt, vcf и как правило, но не всегда, они zip/gzip-архивированы. Базы данных с разными данными из разных источников, это может быть ftp, гугл-диск или просто какое-то место в интернете где создатели этих БД решили разместить свою БД. Кладу я их просто на жесткий диск в директорию, которая содержит поддиректории для каждой отдельной базы данных. Использую либо в первозданном виде, доставая оттуда нужные данные, либо немного их модифицирую и достаю данные.

Comment: @don Rumata
Команда загрузки выглядит для примера вот так: `wget ––tries=100000 -c "https://usf.box.com/shared/static/2hzcx5s6p1xui7oen16xqzndfrkt8l9l" -O dbNSFP4.5a.zip` и запускается через subprocess в python. Ссылки на файла хранятся в питоноском дикте и через for просто прокидываются в wget через subprocess. Но это последовательная загрузка, как я уже сказал, занимает слишком много времени при том, что для большинства файлов не испоьзуется максимально возможная скорость загрузки моего интернет соединения, поэтому хотелось бы загружать параллельно.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-download-file-from-url/#using-a-pool-of-threads-with-the-requests-library

Comment: Точно не помню, но вроде у `aria2c` было про многопоточность. У проекта есть ман на русском.

Comment: @don Rumata
Посмотрел, выглядит очень многообещающе, судя по документации есть все, что нужно, включая докачку и параллельную загрузку, я попробую, спасибо большое, действительно очень полезный ответ)